# Playing Electric Guitar using the fret hand only

Tags: electric-guitar, technique

My husband used to play 6 string electric guitar. Due to being shot in the right arm, he is now paralyzed in his right arm and hand. He plays the keyboard in his band with his left hand now but is longing to have his guitar back in his hand. Is there a tutoring video that someone can share to show him how to get started? He wants to learn the power chords with his left hand on his 6 string electric guitar. We have watched a few videos of some great left handed (only) players on the net, but no videos of how to get him started, like left hand only strumming while playing power chords. He's a hands on by sight kind of person.

Comment: I think more information is needed. To what level does your husband's paralysis currently prevent him from playing guitar, and what steps is he taking to get back into playing guitar? If he played guitar before then I'm not sure he needs tutoring,  unless he is doing something substantially different, such as swapping dexterity? I'm further confused because he can somehow still play keyboard.

Comment: You might like to edit your question and add if his right hand is usable at all, or only his left? Or some other combination. (There are some notable players, not injured, who can sound notes using left-hand hammer on techniques - for example the late Michael Hedges had an clever left hand technique for some songs - you'll probably find videos online.)

Comment: As it has already been suggested, hammering on is the technique to master. Another thing that you could possibly take into consideration is whether different pickups (active?) could make the guitar more sensitive for hammering on. Appropriate pedal effects could shape the sound afterwards as well. I am no guitar player, though. You could also try to contact some of the guitar players you watched, asking for advice on technique and gear.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry to hear that. However, there's really no need for tutoring videos. it's very straightforward. You say he played before, so he should know the names of the E-shape chords with reference to the frets, as in 5th fret barre is A. He can use 2 or 3 fingers for the power chords. Let's take that A on 5th fret. Press 7 on 5th string, and there's an A power chord. To beef it up, press 7 on the D string as well, and include that note. An idea, oft used, is to drop D the bottom string. That means tune it to D. Then, use one finger as a barre across the bottom 3 strings - bearing in mind that NOW the A chord will all happen at the 7th, NOT 5th fret.

Hammering on will make them play fine, so either as a barre, as I said, or, as three fingers of his left hand, all on the same fret, all on the fat three strings.